# Do I need a separate Magento 1 Enterprise license for each IP address if I host multiple Magento websites on the same server?

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, multidomain, licensing

My client requires to have two Magento websites that are completely separate. They need to be hosted on separate domains with separate IP addresses so that users cannot easily tell they are run by the same business. They also require some of the Magento Enterprise features.

Instead of configuring and hosting a separate web server and purchasing and additional Magento license we are considering assigning two IP addresses to the same server and using virtual hosts to the same Magento installation. We may need to copy some directories and use symlinks for others to completely separate things like the media folder. Does this kind of setup require an additional license?

Answer (score 0):

You can check all magento enterprise terms here.

Check all points `4. RESTRICTIONS AND OWNERSHIP` in provided link and you will get your answer.

https://magento.com/legal/terms/enterprise-agreement

Comment: I don't see anything about the number of installations, number or I.P. addresses or number of web servers listed in that agreement.

Comment: see 4.2: `Licensee shall not use the Magento Software on more than five (5) Unique Domains. Licensee shall notify Magento immediately upon the launch of each Unique Domain.`

Comment: according to this you are able to use 5 unique domain and you can add each domain have there unique ip so maximum 5 domain or IPs.